# Can't figure out how I set my PYTHONPATH in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, pythonpath

As soon as I ssh into my ubuntu, my PYTHONPATH shows

```
:/usr/local/opencv-2.4.13/build/modules/python:/usr/local/mxnet/python:/usr/local/caffe/python
```

I don't want these starting settings, but I can't figure out how they got set. They are not set in .bashrc or .profile. Where else should I look?

Comment: `/etc/profile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of places to check (this includes scripts that any of these files source or run, meaning it is not sufficient to `grep` on this list of files for the variable in question):

```
/etc/profile
```

Any files in the folder `/etc/profile.d/`

```
/etc/environment
```

The first existing file of `~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile`

```
/etc/bash.bashrc (or /etc/bashrc , depending on OS)
~/.bashrc
~/.pam_environment (when using ssh)
/etc/motd (when using ssh)
```

Explanation:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

---

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these files exist. This may be inhibited by using the --norc option.

---

> The contents of /etc/motd are displayed by pam_motd(8) after a successful login but just before it executes the login shell.
>       The abbreviation "motd" stands for "message of the day", and this file has been traditionally used for exactly that (it requires much less disk space than mail to all users).
>       On Debian GNU/Linux, the content of /run/motd.dynamic is also displayed. This file is generated by /etc/init.d/motd at boot.

Comment: thank you. I found it in /etc/bash.bashrc. Now this I don't quite understand. /etc/bash.bashrc is obviously shared by every one on the system. Why would someone set an env there to affect everyone. would it be cool, as a general rule, to remove such default setting and free up everyone to set up his her unique env?

Comment: Up to whoever is running the system. If someone "owns" the system, bring it up with them. Someone is probably using it that way, and it doesn't hurt you since you can set up your own variable in your `~/.bashrc` that overwrites the `/etc/bash.bashrc` settings or just `unset` it. It doesn't seem worth messing with tbh.

Comment: I see overriding in .bashrc is obviously a good solution. Thank you.